# ASP.NET Core Web API retrieves blank record in API GET Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API. I have these models:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Mandate : EntityBase
{
    public int? MerchantId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MerchantId")]
    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
}
```

**Model: Mandate**

ViewModel (Dto):

```
public class MandateGetDto
{
    public int? MerchantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

IBaseRepository:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    bool EntityExists(long id);
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public BaseRepository(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await _entities.ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }
    public bool EntityExists(long id)
    {
        return _entities.Any(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

EntityMapper:

```
    public MandateGetDto FromMandateToMandateGetDto(Mandate mandate)
    {
        MandateGetDto mandateDto = new MandateGetDto();
        mandateDto.MerchantId = mandate.MerchantId;
        mandateDto.DueDate = mandate.DueDate;
        mandateDto.StartDate = mandate.StartDate;
        mandateDto.EndDate = mandate.EndDate;

        return mandateDto;
    }
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    #region Mandate
    private readonly IBaseRepository<Mandate> _mandateRepository;

    public IBaseRepository<Mandate> MandateRepository => _mandateRepository ?? new BaseRepository<Mandate>(_context);
    # endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code I have written for the Mandate service which retrieves all the records for the mandates.

MandateService:

```
    public async Task<ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>>> GetAll(int page, int sizeByPage)
    {
        string nextRoute = null, previousRoute = null;
        IEnumerable<Mandate> data = await _unitOfWork.MandateRepository.GetAll();

        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var mandatesDto = data.Select(m => mapper.FromMandateToMandateGetDto(m)).ToList();

        GenericPagination<MandateGetDto> objGenericPagination = GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>.Create(mandatesDto, page, sizeByPage);
        ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>> response = new ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>>(objGenericPagination);
        response.CurrentPage = objGenericPagination.CurrentPage;
        response.HasNextPage = objGenericPagination.HasNextPage;
        response.HasPreviousPage = objGenericPagination.HasPreviousPage;
        response.PageSize = objGenericPagination.PageSize;
        response.TotalPages = objGenericPagination.TotalPages;
        response.TotalRecords = objGenericPagination.TotalRecords;
        response.Data = objGenericPagination;

        if (response.HasNextPage)
        {
            nextRoute = $"/mandates?page={(page + 1)}";
            response.NextPageUrl = _uriPaginationService.GetPaginationUri(page, nextRoute).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            response.NextPageUrl = null;
        }

        if (response.HasPreviousPage)
        {
            previousRoute = $"/mandates?page={(page - 1)}";
            response.PreviousPageUrl = _uriPaginationService.GetPaginationUri(page, previousRoute).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            response.PreviousPageUrl = null;
        }
        return response;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Mandate>> GetMandates()
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.MandateRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IMandateService, MandateService>();
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class AdminController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMerchantService _merchantService;
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;

    public AdminController(DDMDbContext context, IMerchantService merchantService)
    {
        _merchantService = merchantService;
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet("mandates")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>>> GetAllMyMandates(int page, int sizeByPage)
    {
        return await _mandateService.GetAll(page, sizeByPage);
    }

}
```

When I used POSTMAN for the Get Request, I got this response:

```
{
    "current_page": 0,
    "page_size": 0,
    "total_pages": -2147483648,
    "total_records": 1,
    "has_next_page": false,
    "has_previous_page": false,
    "data": []
}
```

Data is blank while total record is 1.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown us the principal part of your code, which is **the controller**

***Controller*** is the reason why your web API even works. So, if you have misconfigured something, it should be present in the controller first or then somewhere else.

Show us the code for the controller.

**Edit**

I am not sure if DbSet is appropriate for the usage, but using the context object works for me.

You should use

`_context.MandateOrWhateverElseItIs.ToListAsync();`

instead of using

`_entities.ToListAsync();`

Using the DbSet can be an issue, I recommend using the context. My application works fruitfully with context.

**Edit**

This is your code in BaseRepository

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public BaseRepository(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await _entities.ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }
    public bool EntityExists(long id)
    {
        return _entities.Any(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

What you should change it to is

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public BaseRepository(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        //Changes are here
        var list = await _context.EntitiesOrWhateverElseItIs.ToListAsync(); //I don't know what the option is, you can look it inside the autocomplete. Be sure to change EntitiesOrWhateverElseItIs with the option you see in autocomplete menu
        return list;
    }
    public bool EntityExists(long id)
    {
        return _entities.Any(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the controller to the code

Comment: Your output seems legitimate, I think the issue is somewhere in the repository

Comment: @mike What is that _entities in Repository code?

Comment: @The issue might be in your Repository code or in the MandateService code ```mandatesDto = data.Select(m => mapper.FromMandateToMandateGetDto(m)).ToList();```

Comment: I updated it in the code. I've been on it for some days now

Comment: I've checked the code several times. Retrieving the data is the issue. What do I do to retrieve the data?

Comment: @mike You should use ```_context.MandateOrWhateverElseItIs.ToListAsync();``` instead of using ```_entities.ToListAsync();```

Comment: @mike check the answer

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. How do you mean? Kindly show explain or show example from the code

Comment: Also I am using that for all the models. That means I will write the Base Repository for each of the model or service

Comment: @mike please check the answer, you just need to change only 1 line of code

Comment: @mike this should work, also then try testing it from visual studio directly, using Swagger or map it by yourself locally